# Water / Snow Movement

Tags: sound-design, sound, foley, sound-effects-recording, film-sound-design

I am working a project that involves a lot of water sound effects and movement. Since, it is an hour in length I have been trying to come up with ways the sounds of the water and movements won't sound repetitive or almost redundant. Any tips or recommendations would be great!

Next, I found this video on Vimeo -

Link: https://vimeo.com/77948519

At the beginning part of the video I was wondering how he was able to get the water sounds to sound 'textured' along with the snow sounds, movement, and snow pieces hitting the snow boarder at 00:26.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Usually the smaller more intimate sounds will provide the detail, so you'll have those larger, slower, heavier wave sounds as the body and you can provide movement and texture and detail with smaller splashes, sprays etc mixed in.

Comment: Thanks, what do you think he used for the snow movement and hits?

Comment: I'm unable to watch the video again at the moment but cornstarch or sand, filtered water sounds, maybe some snow and ice foley would be some things to try.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that shaking different cans of liquid(E.G, cans of non-carbonated soda, wood polish)  produces nice water sounds, but I'm not entirely sure if that's what you are looking for.

(P.S, I would have posted as a comment, but didn't have permission... =|)

Answer (score 0):

To make the big waves not sound repetitive, try putting an lfo on a lowpass filter's cutoff with a slow lfo time. You could also modulate the lfo time up and then down again to give it some movement.